# loop for multiple URLs

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a web page with the following code:-

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel'})
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]

for urls in hrefs:
    pages = requests.get(urls)
    soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')

    Date = soup_2.find_all('li', attrs ={'class' :'sold-date'})
    Sold_Date = [Sold_Date.text.strip() for Sold_Date in Date]
    Address_1 = soup_2.find_all('p', attrs={'class' :'full-address'})
    Address = [Address.text.strip() for Address in Address_1]
```

the above code is returning only the details from the first URL in the hrefs.

```
['Mon 05-Jun-17'] ['261 Keilor Road, Essendon, Vic 3040']
```

I need the loop to run through each URL in hrefs & return similar details from each URL in hrefs.
Please suggest what should i add/edit in the above code.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is behaving in correct manner. 
 You need to store the information in an external list and then return it.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel'})
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]
Data = []
for urls in hrefs:
    pages = requests.get(urls)
    soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')

    Date = soup_2.find_all('li', attrs ={'class' :'sold-date'})
    Sold_Date = [Sold_Date.text.strip() for Sold_Date in Date]
    Address_1 = soup_2.find_all('p', attrs={'class' :'full-address'})
    Address = [Address.text.strip() for Address in Address_1]
    Data.append(Sold_Date + Address)
return Data
```

Comment: Can you please also guide me how can i run the same code for say 10 or 20 pages on the same site, without having to provide the link of each new page every time ?

Comment: If it is working then please approve the answer to close the question.

Comment: You can use another for loop above  this line: 
page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")
i.e extract the URLs and do 
for url in urllist:
   page = requests.get(url)
     {    
        you previous code here 
      }

Comment: I am sorry but i am not that well versed with loops. I am still not able to figure out how can i make the loop run for each page. Can you please help further into this ?

Comment: import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(3):
    page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-{0}?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-{0}date&autoSuggest=true".format(i))
     
The above code is still returning the result from page 1 only.

Comment: You need to parse the Home page to get the links of other pages. Now, store the list of these links in urllist. Now use this code: 
info = []
for url in urllist: 
     requests.get(url); 
     Previous code here.
     *
     *
      for urls in hrefs: 
     *
     *
     *      Previous code here.
      Data.append(Sold_Date + Address)
info.append(Data)
return info

Comment: The home page would not have the selections i have made to reach this url :-

Comment: The home page is simply https://www.realcommercial.com.au, where as the url i am using has lot of criterias filled in the home page. The url i am using is http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true                                                                                         If i will parse the home page, i will loose the selections

Comment: If I am not wrong then you wan to navigate every page of the website and run you script?

Comment: The home page has various regions options to be chosen and i want to run the script for certain specific regions only. As of now i have started with Victoria(VIC) region.

Comment: Then you have extract the urls for every region  and put them in a list. There must be some class under which the regions are defined. extract those links and then run the script.

Comment: just in case if i continue with the same URL "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true" and not with the homepage,, can i have any code like following to scrape multiple pages simultaneously.

Comment: import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for i in range(20):
   url = "http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-{}?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true".format(i)
   page = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
   links = soup.find_all('a', attrs ={'class' :'details-panel'})
   hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `Address` and `Sold_Date` objects on each iteration:

```
# after assignment previous data will be lost
Sold_Date = [Sold_Date.text.strip() for Sold_Date in Date]
Address = [Address.text.strip() for Address in Address_1]
```

Try to initialize empty `list`s outside of loop and extend them

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.realcommercial.com.au/sold/property-offices-retail-showrooms+bulky+goods-land+development-hotel+leisure-medical+consulting-other-in-vic/list-1?includePropertiesWithin=includesurrounding&activeSort=list-date&autoSuggest=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'details-panel'})
hrefs = [link['href'] for link in links]

addresses = []
sold_dates = []
for urls in hrefs:
    pages = requests.get(urls)
    soup_2 = BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')

    dates_tags = soup_2.find_all('li', attrs={'class': 'sold-date'})
    sold_dates += [date_tag.text.strip() for date_tag in dates_tags]
    addresses_tags = soup_2.find_all('p', attrs={'class': 'full-address'})
    addresses += [address_tag.text.strip() for address_tag in addresses_tags]
```

gives us

```
>>>sold_dates
[u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Tue 06-Jun-17',
 u'Mon 05-Jun-17',
 u'Mon 05-Jun-17',
 u'Mon 05-Jun-17']
>>>addresses
[u'141 Napier Street, Essendon, Vic 3040',
 u'5 Loupe Crescent, Leopold, Vic 3224',
 u'80 Ryrie Street, Geelong, Vic 3220',
 u'18 Boase Street, Brunswick, Vic 3056',
 u'130-186 Buckley Street, West Footscray, Vic 3012',
 u'223 Park Street, South Melbourne, Vic 3205',
 u'48-50 The Centreway, Lara, Vic 3212',
 u'14 Webster Street, Ballarat, Vic 3350',
 u'323 Nepean Highway, Frankston, Vic 3199',
 u'341 Buckley Street, Aberfeldie, Vic 3040']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Azat !!